# Setting a text-character limit on an input in HTML

Tags: html

How can I set a character limit within my input fields? And lets the user know how many characters they have left! Thank you

```
<label htmlFor="dropdown" className="label-dropdown">What's this entry about?</label>
<input
    className="dropdown"
    type="text"
    name="dropdown"
    id="dropdown"
    placeholder="Thoughts/Ideas/Goals?"
    value={values.dropdown}
    onChange={handleChange}
```

Comment: you would write the logic in the 'handleChange' function  -what have you tried so far?

Comment: I used maxLength={} and it seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

you can use maxlength attribute in your input. That will help you to get what you want.

```
<input
    className="dropdown"
    type="text"
    name="dropdown"
    id="dropdown"
    placeholder="Thoughts/Ideas/Goals?"
    value={values.dropdown}
    onChange={handleChange}
    maxlength="10" />
```

Also you can check

[maxlength w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp)

Comment: I didn't realize the maxlength attribute took care of : "lets the user know how many characters they have left"